# Restore PFILE files copied directly off of a Bitlocker encrypted directory

Tags: bitlocker, recovery

I have PFILE files copied directly off of a Bitlocker encrypted directory along with a backup of the pfx recovery key. The original computer died. I understand this is not the way to make copies of Bitlocker encrypted files. Is there any way to recover these files?

I imagined one might create a new directory, copy the PFILES files into it, and use Bitlocker somehow with the pfx file.

Possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The regular Bitlocker system works on partitions and therefore does not create any files at all. Therefore it is unclear what you are talking about. May be you are using BitlockerToGo instead of Bitlocker?

Comment: Not intentionally. The whole PC drive was protected. All she did was click and drag files over to the thumb drive.

Comment: And here we have the problem: Bitlocker always encrypts a whole drive, a locked Bitlocker partition can't be mounted without properly unlocked. Hence I would assume that you have some encrypted files using a third party tool, but not something encrypted by Bitlocker.

Comment: A quick internet research showed that PFILES are associated with Microsoft Rights Management service. May be Bitlocker is a requirement for this service but besides that the PFILES have absolutely nothing to do with Bitlocker itself.

Comment: I found this post from someone with the same issue that seems to explain it better. [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256641/cant-open-a-windows-10-encrypted-file-transferred-to-another-pc-because-of-the) Looks like you are correct.